# JWT token expired but it doesnt have expiration time

Tags: go

I'm working in a simple login with golang i have a route that generates a token jwt with library golang-jwt but when i try to verify the token in a middleware, yes it is a valid token but it keep telling me that is expired, i don't know why

this is my code for generate the token:

```
func GenerateToken(user models.User) (string, error) {
    tokenBuilder := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256 , jwt.MapClaims{
        "user":user.Email,
        "nombre":user.Nombre,
        "apellido":user.Apellido,
        "edad":fmt.Sprint(user.Edad),
        "genero":user.Genero,
        "rol":user.Rol,
    })

    tokenBuilder.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)["exp"] = nil

    tokenString, err := tokenBuilder.SignedString([]byte(os.Getenv("SECRET")))

    return tokenString,err
    
}
```

`tokenBuilder.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)["exp"] = nil` it was what i think solve the problem. but didn't work

And my middleware is this

```
type CustomClaims struct {
    jwt.StandardClaims
}

func JWTMiddleware() fiber.Handler {
    return func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        authHeader := c.Get("Authorization")
        if authHeader == "" {
            return c.Status(fiber.StatusUnauthorized).JSON(fiber.Map{
                "message": "No Auth token",
            })
        }

        tokenString := authHeader[7:] //"Bearer "

        token , err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(tokenString, &CustomClaims{}, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
            return []byte(os.Getenv("SECRET")), nil
        })

        if err != nil {
            return c.Status(fiber.StatusUnauthorized).JSON(fiber.Map{
                "message": "Invalid token",
            })
        }

        //Check if is expired
        claims, ok := token.Claims.(*CustomClaims)
        if !ok || !token.Valid {
            return c.Status(fiber.StatusUnauthorized).JSON(fiber.Map{
                "message": "Invalid or expired",
            })
        }

        // Check token expiration time
        if claims.ExpiresAt < time.Now().Unix() {
            return c.Status(fiber.StatusUnauthorized).JSON(fiber.Map{
                "message": "Expired token",
            })
        }

        return c.Next()
    }
}
```

I don't really know if my generated token is right or my middleware is right, in this middleware i try to catch tokens even if this doesn't have expiration time, I'm starting in golang, i investigated but im out, this token work with the middleware created by library but i want mines for different purposes. Thank you and good day i hope i have been clear

I try `tokenBuilder.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)["exp"] = nil` and in my tokenGeneration make a new claim like this `exp:0`

Comment: Try it with an expiration date far in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't set `exp` then `StandardClaims.ExpiresAt` will be it's default value (`int64` so `0`) and, as such, `claims.ExpiresAt < time.Now().Unix()` will be `true` (`time.Now().Unix()` will be greater than `0`!). If you really want to do this then add a check for `0` e.g.

```
if claims.ExpiresAt != 0 && claims.ExpiresAt < time.Now().Unix() {
```

It's worth noting that [`ParseWithClaims`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/golang-jwt/jwt/v4#Parser.ParseWithClaims) verifies `exp` (so you don't really need to!). Note that it will call [`Valid`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/golang-jwt/jwt/v4#StandardClaims.Valid) so "if any of the above claims are not in the token, it will still be considered a valid claim.".

A better option would be to set a valid expiry...

As a further note creating a [Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) such as [this](https://go.dev/play/p/wX8ac5oW6L9) would probably have led you to this conclusion (and if not made your question simpler).